# Warning: validateDOMNesting(…): <form> cannot appear as a descendant of <form> by using semantic-ui-react modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

When I use `Form` in modal of **semantic-ui-react**, it shows that error.

> Warning: `validateDOMNesting(…)`:  cannot appear as a descendant
> of

I know it is show if there are form in form.

Below is my code, there are no one. if i don't use modal, there are no error.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import { Button, Modal, Form } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { Body, Wrapper, Content, Article } from "../../Styles/Wrapper";

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-anonymous-default-export
export default (company_id, company_secret, onSubmit) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Body>
      <Wrapper>
        <Helmet>
          <title>juju</title>
        </Helmet>
        <Content>
          <Article>
            <Modal as={Form}
              onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
              onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
              open={open}
              trigger={
                <Button
                  style={{ marginBottom: 10, backgroundColor: "#FEE500" }}
                  size="large"
                  fluid
                >
                  <span style={{ fontSize: 15 }}>begin</span>
                </Button>
              }
            >
              <Modal.Header>add</Modal.Header>
              <Modal.Content>
                <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                  <Form.Group>
                    <Form.Input
                      placeholder="put id"
                      name="id"
                      {...company_id}
                    />
                    <Form.Input
                      placeholder="put secret"
                      name="secret"
                      {...company_secret}
                    />
                    <Form.Button content="Submit" />
                  </Form.Group>
                </Form>
              </Modal.Content>
            </Modal>
          </Article>
        </Content>
      </Wrapper>
    </Body>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have a `form` inside a `form`. Remove `as={Form}` when rendering the `Modal` component. You should also fix the function arguments since the component receives a `props` object. You should destructure `company_id`, `company_secret`, and `onSubmit`.

```js
export default ({ company_id, company_secret, onSubmit }) => {
  // ...
}
```

And there are a few issues with the `<Form.Input>` components. You should pass them the `value` and `onChange` props. You could create a couple of state variables `companyId` and `companySecret` to manage the input states.

```js
const [companyId, setCompanyId] = useState(company_id)
const [companySecret, setCompanySecret] = useState(company_secret)
```

```
<>
  <Form.Input
    name="id"
    value={companyId}
    onChange={(e) => setCompanyId(e.target.value)}
  />
  <Form.Input
    name="secret"
    value={companySecret}
    onChange={(e) => setCompanySecret(e.target.value)}
  />
</>
```

[image: Edit semantic-ui-modal-fz1su]

P.S. I would suggest using `camelCase` variables everywhere (unless you absolutely have to use `snake_case`) for consistency.

Comment: Thank you so much, It works. and i fix snake_case to cameCase